# Passing values from android app to .Net web service?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access .Net web service from android app and I am facing a very weird issue. The code I found for passing values from android app to .Net web service is like:

```
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("a");
pi.setValue(a);
pi.setType(Integer.class);
```

But in my Android studio it's not even showing the method **setName** or **setValue**. I set *name* like this:

```
 PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
 pi.name="a";
 pi.type=Integer.class;
```

but I am not getting any method to set the value. I am having **ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2.jar** as jar file reference, I downloaded it from 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/k/Downloadksoap2androidassembly252jar.htm

Please let me know where I am doing mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try a version from here? https://code.google.com/archive/p/ksoap2-android/downloads

Comment: I have tried this reference, its not working!! From where this setName or setValue methods are coming, I have no idea.

Comment: It's done with ksoap2-android-assembly-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar, Many thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Finally It's working. Those who are facing the same problem, download

**ksoap2-android-assembly-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

from this link:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/ksoap2-android/downloads